# Node js late response issue(slow api responses)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a **REST API** in which it takes lots of time in **sending a response as my code searches in many fields of collection** and I need that response in my client-side(updated lists)
My issue is that at a certain time I got a blank response from my API i.e **response is sent before searching in DB and got a blank response as result**

**It does search correct but as time spend much it can't respond properly**.how do I solve this issue?

Also, I have tried to send `response.end() at the end` but it doesn't work

Comment: It could be the default timeout kicking in. 2 Minutes is the default for Node Server.

Comment: You have to optimize the query or set => res.setTimeout(0); close res in 2 minute

Comment: okay then what should i do..??I want that response in my client-side code..how to a send my response then?

Comment: @PrashantGupta can you show this on a code??

Comment: update your question and post your query as well... And try to 
do indexing with the fields that are being searched by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the default timeout if that's the reason behind it.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hi!');
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
console.log(server.timeout);
server.timeout = 0; //Set to 0 to disable any kind of automatic timeout behavior on incoming connections.
console.log(server.timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code stop the response in 60 sec, server.timeout value in milliseconds.

```
var server= http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),app.get('host'), function(){
    server.timeout = 60000;
    //console.log(server.timeout);
  });
  console.log("Server listening at http://%s:%s",app.get('host'),app.get('port'));
}
```